# How to show f.__doc__ in latex form using matplotlib?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, latex

I have the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
plt.suptitle(r"$\boldsymbol{f(x)=}$" + f.__doc__)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
fig.savefig("{}.pdf".format(f.__doc__), bbox_inches='tight')
```

and I want  f.**doc**  also to be shown in latex in the `plt.suptitle`.

If I set `f.__doc__`  to `"tan(x)-2x"` I get

[image]

and I'm looking for way to show this:

[image]

I thought maybe setting `f.__doc__`  to `\boldsymbol{\tan(x)-2x}` would help somehow but then i'll get a long latex filename in `fig.savefig`.

Is there a way to get the latex form in the `suptitle` while saving the original filename?

Comment: f-strings might come handy here: `plt.suptitle(f"$\\boldsymbol{{f(x)={f.__doc__}}}$")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to insert the string in your title before you exit math-mode and the `\boldsymbol` environment. For example:

```
plt.suptitle(r"$\boldsymbol{f(x)=" + f.__doc__ + "}$")
```

or

```
plt.suptitle(r"$\boldsymbol{{f(x)={}}}$".format(f.__doc__))
```

(Note in the second option, because curly braces are used by both LaTeX and python, we need double braces `{{ }}` to open and close the `\boldsymbol` environment).

Both yield the same figure:

[image]

If you want the `tan` to not be italic, you would need to enter a backslash before your string. For example:

```
plt.suptitle(r"$\boldsymbol{{f(x)=\{}}}$".format(f.__doc__))
```

[image]